# Why is ${n-1 \choose -1} = 0$ when (-1)! is undefined?

Tags: combinatorics

Why is ${n-1 \choose -1} = 0$ when (-1)! is undefined? Shouldn't ${n-1 \choose -1}$ also be undefined?

Comment: *Shouldn't ${n-1 \choose -1}$ also be undefined ?* - No. It shouldn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By convention $\binom{n}k=0$ when $k>n$ or $k$ is a negative integer. This convention simplifies many manipulations involving sums and binomial coefficients. For example, we can write

$$\binom{n+1}k=\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}$$

without having to worry about whether $k=0$.

Comment: I thought $n$ and $k$ had to be non negative integers? What am I missing or not understanding?

Comment: @Fmonkey2001: As I said, it’s convenient to extend the definition to allow $k$ to be negative. We can even let $n$ be negative if $k\ge 0$ by defining $\binom{x}k=x^{\underline k}$, the [falling factorial](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer-Symbol). In elementary courses this extension is often not used.

Comment: I do remember talking about Pochammer. I'll have to go back to the book and my notes and look into the falling factorial. Thanks!

Comment: @Fmonkey2001: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) is the English-language version of that Wikipedia page. I think you meant to define $\binom{x}k=x^{\underline k}/k!$, didn't you?

Comment: @bof: Yikes! I certainly did. Too late to fix it now, unfortunately; hopefully anyone who reads the comment will read these as well. Thanks!

Comment: As long as $k$ is a nonnegative integer, the $n$ in $\binom nk$ can be any kind of real or complex number, seeing as $\binom nk=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)/k!$ is just a polynomial function of $n$. The *binomal coefficient* $\binom nk$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ which is an infinite series unless $n$ happens to be a nonnegative integer.

Comment: @bof: Yes: that’s why I used $x$ there. Unfortunately, the phone call that ate the $k!$ also ate the explanation of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one conceptual way to think of it:

$n\choose k$ is the number of ways to choose things $k$ things from $n$ objects. So $n-1\choose -1$ is the number of ways to choose $-1$ things from $n-1$ objects. Well, you can't choose $-1$ objects, so ${n-1\choose -1}=0$.

Comment: You also can't choose k things from $-5$ or $3/2$ object and yet binomial coefficients $\binom{-5}k$ and $\binom{3/2}k$ are [usually defined to be] non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n$ is undefined. $~\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n$ is $0.~$ The same happens here.

Comment: I don't see the connection. I don't even see why _a similar kind of thing_ happens here.

Comment: $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$ and $\displaystyle{a\choose n}=\frac{a!}{n!~(a-n)!}$. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to-1}\Gamma(n+1)$ is undefined. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to-1}\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)~\Gamma(a-n)}$ is $0$ for $a\not\in\mathbb Z^-$.